# Centering Bootstrap / FlaskWTForms (Jinja)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask, jinja2

Let me preface by saying I do not know front-end development whatsoever. I've been trying to center this form for what feels like forever, but nothing is working. I'm using Flask Bootstrap and WTForms. Here's the code I have below:

HTML

```
{% block content %}
<body>
<div class="container center_div" align=middle>
    <h2>Indie/Alternative Artist Recommendation</h2>
    <p>Enter 5 artists below and we will provide similar artists you may like</p>
    <br/>
    <form method="Post" action="/results">
    <div class="col-xs-4" align=middle>
        {{ form.artist1.label(class="col-md-6 col-sm-12") }}

        {{ form.artist1(class="form-control") }}

        {{ form.artist2.label(class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12") }}

        {{ form.artist2(class="form-control") }}

        {{ form.artist3.label(class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12") }}

        {{ form.artist3(class="form-control") }}

        {{ form.artist4.label(class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12") }}

        {{ form.artist4(class="form-control") }}

        {{ form.artist5.label(class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12") }}

        {{ form.artist5(class="form-control") }}
    <p><input type=submit value=Go type="button" class="btn btn-default"></p>
    </div>

</form>
 </div>
{% block scripts %}
<script src="{{url_for('.static', filename='js/getArtists.js')}}"></script>
{{super()}}
{% endblock %}
```

And the bit of CSS I have (in my bootstrap.css file):

```
.center_div{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:90%; 
    text-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
...
<div class="col-xs-4" align=middle>
...
```

with

```
...
<div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-12">
...
```

And, please, reset your `bootstrap.css` back to original and do not touch it again. If you want to make mods to CSS you just create your own CSS file and load it on top of (after) `bootstrap.css` (or `bootstrap.min.css`). Use specific selectors when you want your mods on specific elements and use the same selectors as Bootstrap when you want your mods to be general.

You can't learn CSS in a day, so... if you need professional level CSS in your project, Bootstrap will not provide it for you. You should get a frontend dev to look at your app before you launch.